# What does boost::condition_variable::timed_wait() return on spurious wakeups?

Tags: c++, boost-thread

The [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable.timed_wait) says:

> Returns:
>    false if the call is returning because the time specified by abs_time was reached, true otherwise.

But what is returned if there is a spurious wakeup?

Comment: Sounds like "otherwise" to me.

Comment: Yes :-) It is just that it seems to return false for me. I was wondering if anybody has actually observed what happens.

Comment: The wording in the documentation I think is wrong, "natural instinct" tells you that it MUST return false, otherwise the function would yield a false positive (i.e. you'd might think that the condition really had been set).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the condition variable could figure that it is a spurious wake-up there would be no need to return, would it?

You need to check if the data protected by the mutex and the condition variable has changed to detect a spurious wake-up. The condition variable can not do that for you.

Comment: Ok, I guess that means that it can return both true or false on a spurious wakeup.

Comment: @Torleif Nope, there are no spurious timeouts.